# Wanting to create a custom mute/unmute button for the audio on a full screen video background

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video, controls

I currently have a full screen background video which I have looping with audio, I want to make a custom button so when visitors visit the site can mute/unmute the audio.

I have tried using this code...

```
<video id="bg" loop autoplay preload="auto" poster="../img/still.jpg">
   <source src="vid/vidbg2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   <source src="vid/vidbg.webm" type="video/webm" />
   <source src="vid/vidbg.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
   Your browser does not support this video
</video>
<div id="video_controls">
   <button id="mutebtn">mute</button>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript

```
<script>
    var mutebtn;
    function intitializePlayer(){
    //set object references
    vid = document.getElementById("bg");
    mutebtn = document.getElementById("mutebtn");
    //add event listener
    mutebtn.addEventListener("click,vidmute,false");
  }
    function.vidmute(){
    if(vid.muted){
    vid.muted = false;
    mutebtn.innerHTML = "mute";
} else {
    vid.muted = true;
    mutebtn.innerHTML = "Unmute";
}
}
</script>
```

Think I might be barking up the wrong tree?

Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: try `mutebtn.addEventListener("click",vidmute,false);` ... quotes around the event, not the whole thing

Comment: @Offbeatmammal thanks for the reply, but still doesn't seem to work, really puzzling me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like three small changes where needed
1/ quotes only around the `click` not the whole of the addEventListener parameters
2/ call the initialize
3/ remove extra period from `function.vidmute`

```
<script>
var mutebtn;
intitializePlayer()  // **don't forget to call the initialize**

function intitializePlayer(){
    //set object references
    vid = document.getElementById("bg");
    mutebtn = document.getElementById("mutebtn");
    //add event listener
    mutebtn.addEventListener("click",vidmute,false);   // **quotes only around the event** 
}

function vidmute(){   // **there was an extra '.' between function and vidmute**
    if(vid.muted){
        vid.muted = false;
        mutebtn.innerHTML = "mute";
    } else {
        vid.muted = true;
        mutebtn.innerHTML = "Unmute";
    }
}
</script>
```