# Webflow Video Background - Mute/UNMUTE button

Tags: javascript, audio, mute, webflow

I have a page built in webflow, it has a video background put in it. It seems to come muted by default which is fine.

I would just like to include a small button in the corner so the user is able to unmute and mute the audio at the very least. If we can add volume that is even better.

Here is the [page](http://sf-com.webflow.io/) where it is currently parked until publishing.

I have tried a few other code examples on here with no success, for example this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987336/wanting-to-create-a-custom-mute-unmute-button-for-the-audio-on-a-full-screen-vid)

::: Here is an update ::: I will go through all your suggestions, and here below the following link is a snippet of what I came up with after following this post

( [   [WANTING TO CREATE CUSTOM MUTE..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987336/wanting-to-create-a-custom-mute-unmute-button-for-the-audio-on-a-full-screen-vid)  ])

```js
<!-- MUTEBUTTON \/ MUTEBUTTON -->

<script>  
 
var themutebtn;
intitializePlayer()  // **don't forget to call the initialize**

function intitializePlayer(){
    //set object references
    vid = document.getElementById("intro_video");
    themutebtn = document.getElementById("audioswitch1");
    //add event listener
    themutebtn.addEventListener("click",vidmute,false);   // **quotes only around the event** 
}

function mute_switch(){   // **there was an extra '.' between function and vidmute**
    if(vid.muted){
        vid.muted = false;
        themutebtn.innerHTML = "mute";
    } else {
        vid.muted = true;
        themutebtn.innerHTML = "Unmute";
    }
}

  
</script>

<!-- MUTEBUTTON /\ MUTEBUTTON -->
```

IVE BEEN WORKING AT THIS FOR A WHILE, SO I MAY HAVE VEARED OFF INTO SOME STRANGE TANGENT, PLEASE LET ME KNOW IF I AM WAY OFF TRACK AND IF THERE IS A BETTER WAY TO DO THIS. THANK YOU!!  XD

Here is the other portion of the code...

```html
<div id="audioswitch_div" class="audioswitch_div">

  <button  id="audioswitch1" class="mutebutton w-button" value="muted">MUTE</button>

</div>
```

Comment: whats wrong with the current button?

Comment: We will need to see the block of html that is playing the sound and the javascript you have so far. It's likely a <video> tag that is set to muted.

Comment: The post you linked should work, but you are going to have to change a number of things in the solution code. Also, after an inspect of your site I can see in that you have a video tag that is set to `muted`. You will need to select that item using javascript and change `muted` to `false`/`true` when the button is clicked.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: I think that video in the page does not have sound

Comment: I have made an update, I may have to call it a night soon. Thanks all for the suggestions, hope these updates help.... hopefully we can figure this out.